# java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to add value to Array

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

I have a task to make my own Dynamic Array without using any `ArrayList`s or other pre-made classes for Arrays in java.
I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` error when I try to add my object (for example it's Integer).

```
Dinaminis<Integer> array = new Dinaminis<>();
array.ideti(5);
```

And my Dinaminis class looks like this:

```
public class Dinaminis<T> implements DArray<T> 
{    
    private Object[] array;
    private int kiek;
    private Object[] temp;

    public Dinaminis() {
        array = new Object[10];
        kiek = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void ideti(Object o) {
        if (array.length == kiek) {
            temp = new Object[kiek*2];
        }
        for (int i=1; i < kiek; i++){
            temp[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = temp;
        array[kiek] = o;
        kiek++;
    }
}
```

The thing is when I want to use "ideti" method, I want to check if the array is full, and if it's full it should create a double sized array. But I get an error even before my array is full.

Comment: What if `array.length == kiek` is `false`?

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't make `temp` an instance variable (just local to the method), and `System.arraycopy` is a lot faster than hand-copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you store your `array` as your it's generic type `T`. I would pass in to the `Class<T>` to the `Dinaminis` constructor, then you can use `Array.newInstance()`. Also, I'd prefer to use `System.arraycopy()` and override `toString()` like

```
public class Dinaminis<T> implements DArray<T> {
    private T[] array;
    private int kiek;
    private Class<T> cls;

    public Dinaminis(Class<T> cls) {
        this.cls = cls;
        array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(cls, 10);
        kiek = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void ideti(T o) {
        if (kiek == array.length) {
            T[] temp = (T[]) Array.newInstance(cls, array.length * 2);
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, array.length);
            array = temp;
        }
        array[kiek++] = o;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.format("len = %d [", array.length));
        for (int i = 0; i < kiek; i++) {
            if (i != 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(array[i]);
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Then you could test it with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DArray<Integer> t = new Dinaminis<Integer>(Integer.class);
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        t.ideti(i);
    }
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Output is

```
len = 20 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Obviously `len` was added to this output for pedagogical reasons, and in real code I probably wouldn't display it (except perhaps in a log message).

Answer (score 3):

Your ideti method is wrong. This should work:

```
public void ideti(Object o) {
    if (array.length == kiek) {
        temp = new Object[kiek*2];
        // only copy old array to new array when old one is full
        for (int i=0; i < kiek; i++){ // index starts at 0, not 1
            temp[i] = array[i];
        }
        array = temp;
    } 
    array[kiek] = o;
    kiek++;
}
```

Your problem was that the loop that copies the old array to the new one was executed even when the original array wasn't full, in which case `temp` wasn't initialized, which led to `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your temp array before using it.

You do initialize it inside of the **if** but not outside the **if**

temp = new Object[kiek*2];

so allocation of the double sized array should only happen when the size of the array is complete

```
if (array.length == kiek)  //check if array size is reached
{ 

  temp = new Object[kiek*2]; //allocate a double sized array

  for (int i=1; i < kiek; i++) //copy elements - are you sure you don't want to start with i=0? You won't copy the first element if you start at 1
  {
    temp[i] = array[i];
  }
  array = temp;
}
```